# Is there a way to force pandas `to_numeric` to always return float64?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading data from a file into a data frame using `pandas#read_csv`, using `pandas#to_numeric` as a [converter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for one of the columns. I'd like this column to be always read as a `float64`. However pandas will return either `float64` or `int64`.

Is there a way to force pandas `to_numeric` to always return `float64`?

Alternately, is there another way to leverage a converter to return `float64`?

```py
pd.read_csv("foo.csv", converters={
    "some_col": pd.to_numeric,
})
```

Comment: `converter={'some_col':lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x).astype('float64')}`?

Comment: why not `dtype` option?

Comment: @MarkWang From docs: If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

Comment: @QuangHoang That worked, thanks! Would you care to post this as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarkWang I have more columns, and more converters. So can't _replace_ converters with dtypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the dtype with `astype()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", converters={
    "some_col": lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x).astype('float64'),
})
```

Which is somewhat equivalent to:

```
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
df['some_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['some_col']).astype('float64')

# or 
# df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].astype('float64')
```

I would recommend the second approach since it is more readable to me. But it's just purely personal, `converters` exists for a reason :-).